# TypeError: Expected float32 multiplying placeholder with gradient

Tags: tensorflow

hey there i am trying to familiarise myself with tensorflow and having trouble with this error, google isn't delivering much...

the error stems from the 'c' placeholder multiplication. error disappears when i delete it

code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = x**2
g = tf.gradients(y, x) * c

tf.Session().run(g, {x:[1,1],c:[-1,-1]})
```

error:

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that [`tf.gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients) returns a *list* of tensors (even when its argument is a single tensor... which is unfortunately inconsistent with some of the other TensorFlow APIs). Therefore, you have to take the 0th element of the return value:

```
g = tf.gradients(y, x)[0] * c
```